# How to save value of an element selected by the array style in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Let's say we have following this:

```
<p class="first">This is paragraph 1.</p> 
<p class="second">This is paragraph 2.</p> 
<p id="third">This is paragraph 3.</p>
<p>This is paragraph 4.</p>
```

We can save the value of an element in `value` variable and show like this.

```
var value = $('p').slice(3,4);
value.text(); // result --> This is paragraph 4
```

Above way has no problem if we know the number of element but we'll get problem if we have a lot of elements and we want to do with looping. why I get error if I do like this?

```
$('p')[3].text();
```

What should I do if I want to loop and get values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop like this:

```
$('p').each(function(i) {
  alert($(this).text());
  //or this:
  alert($('p').eq(i).text());
});
```

When you do `[3]` you're getting the DOM element `<p>` not the jQuery object, which has the `.text()` method.

```
$('p')[3] == DOM Element, doesn't have `.text()`
$('p').eq(3) == jQuery object, has `.text()`
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery objects can function as arrays of DOM elements, not other jQuery objects.
Therefore, writing `$(...)[3]` gives you a raw DOM element, not a jQuery object.

You need to call the [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) function:

```
$('p').eq(3).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with what you're trying to do is that `$('p')[3]` will not return a jQuery object, and therefore it does not have a `text()` function.

Instead, use something like this:

```
$('p.eq(3)')

// OR

$('p').eq(3)
```

A general rule of thumb is that if you aren't sure whether or not an object has any jQuery methods, you're probably well off simply wrapping it in `$(...)` or `jQuery(...)`, the latter being used more if you are using `jQuery.noConflict();` (and therefore using Prototype or some other library that uses `$` as its variable).

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your error is that you get the actual DOM element when you get it using array notation.  The DOM element doesn't have a text() function.  To get all the values, use each.

```
var values = [];
$('p').each( function(i) {
    values[i] = $(this).text();
}
```

To get a particular element, use eq();

```
var value = $('p').eq(3).text();
```